# Is there any scientifically proven way to get criteria or factors, why a user accepts a software?

Tags: usability, users, psychology

Sometimes I notice the effect in my company, that a software is accepted by a project team - even though in Usability Testing the software (not having monopoly in functionality) turned out to be more negative.

That's why I am asking myself, which criteria, besides Usability, are leading to acceptance by user.

Maybe somebody of you knows any (scientifically) proven way, to get these factors from stakeholders. I would be also grateful for related research and links.

Comment: Are we talking new software the company has purchased or legacy software? Sometimes it's a simple case of "we've always used this and it works so why change?"

Comment: This highly depends on your users; their goals and motivations determine greatly how much they're willing to 'put up with' software. For example, many professional software tools are a UX hellhole, but are still widely used for the utility they bring. These users accept the lack of usability and learn to work with what they have. Entertainment driven software on the other hand has tons of alternatives and users are therefore less willing to accept bad usability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Related research:

Fred Davis worked on a Technology Acceptance Model (TAM) in the 1980's that basically said it boiled down to perceived usability and usefulness. This is similar to Wanda's answer, although it's important to realize that perception does not always turn out to reflect reality.

Further work (e.g. Venkatesh & Davis) talks about the importance of supporting information such social influence and other facilitating conditions. So things like what other businesses in the sector are using, what support plans are available, regulatory quirks, and budget vs. perceived costs, could be among those factors.

Those are approaches from MIS (think of UX from a business point of view).

Comment: I added a note that this answer is about the related research. For how-to's on **requirement elicitation**, I'd probably turn to the **BABOK** as a starting point (business analysis body of knowledge) and also system analysis and design disciplines, but don't have a name springing to mind at the moment.